# How to round-off the Total amount in Woocommerce Checkout and Invoice to the nearest whole number? Variations used in products

Tags: wordpress, hook-woocommerce, invoice

I used below code as mentioned in the answer of other questions but it didn't work. Just wish to do the normal rounding and remove the decimal part in final Total cart value(amount plus tax plus shipping value) displayed at checkout page AND the Total amount shown at Invoice generated by Invoice plugin. Variations are used in the product.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_excluding_tax', 'round_price', 10, 1 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_including_tax', 'round_price', 10, 1 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_tax_round', 'round_price', 10, 1);
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price', 'round_price', 10, 1);

function round_price( $price ){
// Return rounded price
return round( $price );
}
```